ion-header getting behind the status bar
I don't know why, but my header is getting behind the statusbar after updating the ionic version from 5 to 6
I would like the header to start by default below the statusbar
here is my code.
`


Messages



<ion-content [fullscreen]="true">
... MY OBJECTS IS HERE
`
